# Plotting wind speed and direction like example plot shown here in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a bunch of data points in a Pandas DataFrame that include `wind_speed`, `wind_dir`, and `time` values.

I want to plot it so that I can get a plot similar to this:
[image]

However, I'm not sure how to do this. I've made plots using `matplotlib` function of `barbs` but wanted to get something like this plotted instead. I've been searching around trying to figure out how to create this sort of plot, but can't seem to find anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plt.quiver()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) for this. It needs four input parameters: X, Y define the arrow locations, U, V define the arrow directions. I created `U` and `V` based on `wind_speed` and `wind_dir` with basic trigonometry.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 10
wind_speed = np.random.random(n)
wind_dir = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, n)
time = list(range(n))
Y = [0] * n

U = np.cos(wind_dir) * wind_speed
V = np.sin(wind_dir) * wind_speed

plt.figure()
plt.quiver(time, Y, U, V)
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Quick question, is the y-axis the wind speed? I'm confused on those units as the numbers are so small. If it's not wind speed, would it be possible to change it to that?

Comment: No it is not, currently the wind speed is the length of the arrow. To get the wind speed as y-axis you can do `V = wind_speed`.

Comment: Note that I am using random values in my example

Comment: Ah, so instead of using ```V = np.sin(wind_dir) * wind_speed``` I'd use ```V = wind_speed```?

Comment: Yes, exactly that